# LINQ count XML elements with multiples

Tags: c#, xml, linq, group-by, count

Having a bit of an issue here, and maybe because I'm tired I'm having trouble actually explaining my problem with words, but what I want is basically a group by, except the XML elements can have multiple of the same kind of element. I'm trying to do this in C#, using LINQ Example:
I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <test1>
        <test2>1</test2>
    </test1>
    <test1>
        <test2>2</test2>
    </test1>
    <test1>
        <test2>1</test2>
        <test2>3</test2>
        <test2>4</test2>
    </test1>
    <test1>
        <test2>1</test2>
        <test2>2</test2>
    </test1>
    <test1>
        <test2>5</test2>
    </test1>
</test>
```

I want to count how many test1 elements have a test2 element with a value of 1, 2 etc., so the output should be this:

1: 3
2: 2
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1

but I can't seem to make the program care about test2 elements after the first one in a given test1 element. Also, first post here, so if I screwed up something go easy on me

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I ended up having a spark of inspiration now in the morning, and I figured it out on my own:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var test = xd.Root.Descendants("test2").GroupBy(x => x.Value);
foreach (var e in test)
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Key}: {e.Count()}");
```

Or at least it gives the correct answer and it seems like it does what I want

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", test.XPathSelectElements("//test2")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value, (k, g) => $"{k}: {g.Count()}")
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two steps:

First, extract the unique `test2` values that you want to count each `test1` for:

```
var test2Values = xd.Descendants("test2").Select(d => d.Value).Distinct();
```

Second, for each value of `test2`, count how many `test1` contain that particular `test2` value:

```
var countOfT1WithT2Values = test2Values.Select(t2v => new { t2v, t1Count = xd.Descendants("test1").Where(t1 => t1.Descendants("test2").Any(t2 => t2.Value == t2v)).Count() });
```

Note: This isn't particularly efficient, as it makes multiple passes over the XML. If you need efficiency, you should use a loop over the `test1` descendants:

```
var countOfT1WithT2Values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var t1 in xd.Descendants("test1")) {
    foreach (var t2 in t1.Descendants("test2").Select(dt2 => dt2.Value)) {
        if (countOfT1WithT2Values.TryGetValue(t2, out var countForT2))
            countOfT1WithT2Values[t2] = countForT2 + 1;
        else
            countOfT1WithT2Values[t2] = 1;
    }
}
```